# DNS query in android source code

Tags: android

Can someone please point out the code in android source code, where a DNS query is being made?

I tried to locate the code where the actual DNS query is sent from an application, but i couldn't.

Any help would be great.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Normally you don't make an explicit DNS query in Java.

When you [create a `Socket`](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/java/net/Socket.html#Socket(java.lang.String,%20int)) you can pass a hostname and the Java VM gets the OS to perform the DNS query on its behalf.  This is why you don't need to configure DNS settings for your Java VM.

There are pure Java implementations of DNS, but I don't believe any of these are supplied with Android.