# Calculating DNS resolve delay

Tags: android, android-ndk

Does anyone know any tools that I could use to calculate a DNS resolve delay on a device?

Answer (score 0):

This answer gives some insight. You can create a socket to a non-existent site and the time to do that will be the DNS resolution time.
[DNS query in android source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182674/dns-query-in-android-source-code)

I'm not aware of an Android API to query the DNS directly, but perhaps there is a Java library you can use, or roll your own.

Comment: I want to understand the delay that is caused in each query. So may be 1st time it might take more time, but consecutive requests to same url will probably reduce the delay considering DHCP server is running its own caching server

Comment: DHCP really has nothing to do with DNS. It is possible that the router you are connecting to, or (possibly) the Android phone, or even the ISP, are caching the DNS query result. This is very common, and so successive lookups will often be quicker. The speed and how it changes over time varies according to a lot of factors, so you may not find consistency.

Comment: As far as I understand, when you are connected to a new network you will get new DNS server which in most of the cases assigned by DHCP itsel. Correct me if I am wrong. Some references might help.

Comment: Yes, the DHCP server will provide the IP address of the dns server(s) but that happens when you connect to the network. Once connected, apps will make DNS queries direct to the DNS servers.

Answer (score 0):

The [InetAddress](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/InetAddress.html) API will be able to help your write your own. However it does not provide for low level configuration such as changing the DNS address etc.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding @Dan S response... I add my code snippet:

```
long startTS, endTS;
String addressName;
startTS = System.currentTimeMillis();
addressName = InetAddress.getByName(hostNameOrIp);
endTS = System.currentTimeMillis();
Log.d(TAG, "Elapsed time: "+(endTS-startTS));
```

Hope it helps someone